# Excel macro to read input from files created today only

Tags: vba, excel

I have an application that exports daily reports in txt format. 
I have a macro that extracts certain lines of data from those reports and puts them in an output xls file. my macro's input directory is curently a separate folder that i manually move today's reports into.

I'd like for my macro to be able to just read from the default report folder and only read files created with today's date.

the naming convention of the report files is as follows:
1101_16_16_AppServiceUser_YYYYMMDDhhmmssXXX.txt
not sure what the last 3 digits on the file name represents, but they're always numbers.

Help?

WOW that was fast! thanks... fist time using stackoverflow.
I guess i should include the code that pulls data and dumps it to excel... here it is:

```
Sub PullLinesFromEPremisReport()
Dim FileName, PathN, InputLn As String
Dim SearchFor1, SearchFor2, OutpFile As String
Dim StringLen1, StringLen2 As Integer
Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim bridgekey As String

PathO = "C:\Documents and Settings\GROMERO\Desktop\CM reconciliation\output\"
PathN = "C:\Documents and Settings\GROMERO\Desktop\CM reconciliation\input\"

FileName = Dir(PathN)

While FileName <> ""
    colFiles.Add (FileName)
    FileName = Dir

Wend

SearchFor1 = "BRIDGE KEY"

StringLen1 = Len(SearchFor1)


OutpFile = "RESULTS.xls"
Open PathO & OutpFile For Output As #2

For Each Item In colFiles
    Open PathN & Item For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1) = True
               Line Input #1, InputLn
               If (Left(LTrim$(InputLn), StringLen1) = SearchFor1) Then
                    bridgekey = InputLn
           End If

    Loop

Close #1
Next Item

Close #2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel's answer is correct, but using the FileSystemObject requires a couple of steps:

Make sure you have a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime":
[image]
[image]

Then, to iterate through the files in the directory:

```
Sub WorkOnTodaysReports()

'the vars you'll need
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fldr As Folder
Dim fls As Files
Dim fl As File

Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Reports")
Set fls = fldr.Files

For Each fl In fls

    'InStr returns the position of the substring, or 0 if not found
    '    EDIT: you can explicitly use the reliable parts of your file name
    '    to avoid false positives
    If InStr(1, fl.Name, "AppServiceUser_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")) > 0 Then

        'Do your processing

    End If

Next fl

End Sub
```

EDIT:  So I *think*, from the code you posted, you could send `PathN` to the main Reports folder like you desire, then just modify your `While` statement like so:

```
While FileName <> ""

    If InStr(1, FileName, "AppServiceUser_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")) > 0 Then

        colFiles.Add (FileName)

    End If

    FileName = Dir

Wend
```

Comment: OP, I think if you add a "vba" tag to the question, the code highlighting will work maybe??  just a guess

Comment: This is an unreliable method. Go with the 2nd option suggested by Daniel. Reason being File Format is `YYYY MM DD hh mm ss X X X` Ex: So if I am looking for a file of 18th Aug (2012 08 18) then the above will fail on `2012 08 19 20 12 08 184`

Comment: If your file naming is an automatic output from another application and you can rely on "AppServiceUser_YYYYMMDD...." then you could add to the `If`, like: "AppServiceUser_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")).  OP stated that File Format contained the "YYYYMMDD" in the middle of the file name.  You are correct though, if the string showed up anywhere else it would produce a false positive.  Ack, not sure how to do a literal " in a comment.  Updating answer.

Comment: Yes. This will fail the 18th Aug Check `1101_16_16_AppServiceUser_20120819201208188.txt` This is as per what OP mentioned `the naming convention of the report files is as follows: 1101_16_16_AppServiceUser_YYYYMMDDhhmmssXXX.txt not sure what the last 3 digits on the file name represents, but they're always numbers.`

Comment: + 1 :) Adding "AppServiceUser_" as you did will sort that out :)

Comment: Only possible issue with Daniel's `> Date` method is if the timestamps represent a date in the past/future, but the file was created on a different date.  Also, it should be `= Date` to find _Today's_ reports

Comment: Yes, I guess that was a typo by him. I am sure he meant "="

Comment: @Andy Actually, the .DateCreate returns the day and time, so using = instead of > would make you miss the majority of the files. More accurately it should be >=.

Comment: Would still have an issue if the file was created same day but before the code was run.  Could maybe wrap both in a Format("YYYYMMDD") and compare?  Need to avoid comparing the time at all.  Thought:  Does comparing to `Date` make an implicit conversion?

Comment: yes the file naming is automatic output from an application and AppServiceUser_YYMMDD will always be in the file naming.

Comment: Okay.  Well, your existing code iterates through the files in the folder in a way I've never used before..  But, it appears you don't need the FileSystemObject stuff at all actually...  see edit.

Comment: Cool, welcome to SOF!  I'm fairly new myself.  Remember to accept answers that work to give folks cred. :)

Answer (score 3):

Two ways you can do this off the top of my head. Assuming you are using a `File` via the `FileSystemObject`.

Do an `Instr` on the `file.Name` looking for `Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")` within the string.

Or use a far simpler approach loop through the files and within your loop do this:

```
If File.DateCreate >= Date Then
    'Do something
end if
```

Where `File` is the actual variable used to for looping through the files.

Comment: + 1 But I wouldn't recommend 1st method. 2nd method is good to go. See my comment in Andy's answer.

Comment: Indeed. I listed the 1st method because it would technically work. However, as we didn't clearly indicate it is likely to cause false positives.

Answer (score 1):

```
If fileName like "*AppServiceUser_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") & _
                                              "#########.txt" Then
    'good to go
End If
```